# Xcode динамический дизайн

Tags: swift, xcode

Подскажите с помощью каких функции в xcode лучше реализовать динамический дизайн, который будет подгружаться от количества записей в базе данных, пример структуры на картинке ниже

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ БД - массив каких-то данных (например, `data = [String]()`).

По ним проходитесь циклом `for`, в цикле добавляете `label.text = "Answer: \(data[i])"`

Причём рекомендую использовать `UIStackView` для обертки над вашими `UILabel`

```
for i in 0..<data.count {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Answer: \(data[i])"
    stackView.addArrangedView(label)
}

view.addSubview(stackView)
```